# ASP.NET Core builtin Authentication middleware doesn't cache openid-config

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm using `ASP.NET Core` to write my APIs.
I have noticed, when my API is peaked with huge amount of requests, then many requests get stuck on the authentication step.

The authentication step is the step that validates the `Bearer` token is legit against the authority provider.
The authority provider in my case is Azure AD.

Using Application Insights, I can see that any API requests, first go to the `openid-configuration` API, to get the relevant stuff from the authority provider in order to be able to validate the Bearer token.

[image]

I'm wondering why the middleware doesn't cache the openid configuration, as this doesn't change very often -- and even if this is a simple call, when my service peaks to ~1500 RPS, this becomes a real burden.

Wondering what setting I have missed that allows me to cache this response. (hopefully such setting exist)

Thank you!

### UPDATE #1 (added code):

The way I enable the middleware is as follows (in the `Startup.ConfigureServices` class/method)

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Audience = _settings.AadAudience;
        options.Authority = new Uri(
                baseUri: _settings.AzureAdInstance,
                relativeUri: _settings.AadTenantId.ToString())
            .ToString();
    });

services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter());
});
```

Comment: Can you share the authentication middleware code?

Comment: It is the default/built-in middleware provided by ASP.NET core

Comment: Did you find a solution? i currently have the same issue in .Net 5 web api

Comment: I'm no longer monitoring this so can't tell. I'm wondering if it still happens on dotnet 6/7